# C# WPF: Не отображается текст на кнопке на кнопке после применения стиля

Tags: c#, wpf

Создал стиль для кнопки, чтобы при наведении ярче загоралась обводка и текст, а при выключенном состоянии они были более тусклыми.

Это работает, но почему-то перестал отображаться текст, записанный в `Content`

**`Style`**

```xml
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Background="#222222"
                        BorderBrush="#00a600"
                        TextBlock.Foreground="#c8c8c8"
                        TextBlock.FontSize="14"
                        TextBlock.FontWeight="Medium">
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#222222" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="14" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Medium" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00ff00" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#222222" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="14" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Medium" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#006400" />
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#9b9b9b"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**`Button`**

```xml
<Button x:Name="TestButton"
    Content="Текст кнопки"
    Height="50" Width="150"
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
</Button>
```

**При этом текста из `Content` не видно**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Можно ли как-то упростить мой код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто, у вас нет ничего, что выводит текст.

```xml
<Border x:Name="border"
        BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Background="#222222"
        BorderBrush="#00a600"
                                
        TextBlock.Foreground="#c8c8c8"
        TextBlock.FontSize="14"
        TextBlock.FontWeight="Medium"> 
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Для меня это было самое неочевидное)

Comment: А почему может не отображаться изображение? Не особо хочется создавать новый вопрос из-за этого, вот код: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/G0feHGVS)

Comment: @denisnumb потому что его например нет в ресурсах или на диске по этому пути например.

Comment: Я не назначил его как ресурс, все ок, извините, что отвлек

Comment: Могу я еще уточнить, почему не меняется цвет текста на кнопке при наведении мыши? *(разметка из вопроса)* Опять же не хочется создавать отдельный вопрос, но если надо - могу)

Comment: @denisnumb когда я писал ответ, у меня менялся с серого на белый. Так что не знаю.